# Who discovered Sexual intercourse

Tags: sexuality, adam, eve-chava

Who discovered sexual intercourse . How did Adam HaRishon know how to procreate with Chava. Did G-d tell him and then it was passed down?

Comment: Couldn't he have learnt it from [the animals](https://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0102.htm#19)?

Answer (score 0):

Yalkut Shimoni [here](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%98_%D7%A9%D7%9E%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%99_%D7%A2%D7%9C_%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%AA_%D7%91_%D7%9B%D7%92)

> אמר רבי אלעזר: מאי דכתיב זאת הפעם? מלמד שבא אדם על כל בהמה וחיה, ולא
> נתקררה דעתו, עד שעה שנזדווגה לו חוה.
>
> Adam tried having intercourse with every domesticated and wild animal
> and only felt it was right after he had intercourse with Chava.

Comment: R Steinsaltz brings commentaries that this is meant figuratively (anyway, imagine a lizard, spider or crow), meaning he looked for a species that would be compatible wit him